# Why the difference between network addresses reported by hostname and ping?

Tags: networking, dns, hostname, ping

I have tried `hostname` and `ping` in a cluster machine, with different outputs. I am wondering what is the difference between the two? For example, on the same machine, `hostname` outputs `node4.XXX` and

```
ping -c 1 $(hostname)
```

outputs `pc333.XXX`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `hostname` command outputs the **hostname** of the system from the systems local hostname configuration (could be /etc/hostname or /proc/sys/kernel/hostname or other depending on OS).

The command `ping -c 1 <hostname>` is going to perform a lookup through the libc resolver (which may or may not be DNS. e.g., /etc/hosts is not DNS) of the `<hostname>` specified and then perform a reverse DNS lookup of the IP address returned and report that name in the output of the ping command.

As a concrete example, suppose that the local system **hostname** is **fred** as specified in `/etc/hostname`.  The `hostname` command will return **'fred'**.  The command `ping -c 1 fred` will perform a DNS lookup of `fred` (either just `fred` or `fred` fully qualified such as `fred.domain.com` if default domain is `domain.com`).  Assume that DNS returns IP address `x.x.x.x`.  `ping` will then perform a reverse DNS lookup of IP address `x.x.x.x`, if no name is returned `ping` will output the IP address `x.x.x.x`, otherwise `ping` will output whatever named was returned from the reverse lookup which could be a different name such as `ethel.domain.com`.

Comment: Well, actually, its going to be a lookup through the libc resolver. Which may or may not be DNS. e.g., `/etc/hosts` is not DNS.

Comment: @derobert Thank you, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks, that clears things up. I have additional question : what is the typical scenario of using address returned by ``hostname``. For example, can it be used by other machines?

Comment: @Richard - you should ask that as a [new question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: This is why your locally configured hostname should resolve to your actual IP address.